# Button hover effect by default

Tags: jquery

My `html form` has a bunch of `buttons` and one of them listens to `Enter` event. Therefore, I want to visually differentiate this button from others. It would be great if I could make it look as if it was hovered by default or have the same `hover` effect without a cursor above. In other frameworks such as `ExtJS` there are properties like `toggled` which do exactly what I want. I wish there was something similar to that in `jquery`.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap by any chance?

Comment: No, I do not use it.

Comment: In that case, follow what Kilenaitor has suggested.  And this is what you'd most likely to change: .myprimarybutton {
  color: 'some color code';
  background-color: 'some color code';
  border-color: 'some color code';
}

Comment: @ Yellen. That is right. Thanks. I did it almost like that and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just use CSS to style that one button in particular with an additional class?

`<button class="form">`

for the standard buttons and then just for your one special button

`<button class="form pressed">` and have an additional css selector

```
.pressed {
    *styles*
}
```

That way you can do it without jQuery.